# Building a graph given constraints

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-algorithm

Given:

- A list of nodes
- A list of nodes those nodes may connect to
- The constraints that every node must connect to one and only one other node (one-way connection)
- All the nodes must be reachable starting from any node

Is there an algorithm that would give me such a graph if it is possible to construct or otherwise give me the graph with the highest number of node possible?

Is it possible to do in polynomial time?

Otherwise, is there an algorithm that gives a good enough solution fast enough?

Comment: Polynomial time, of course - O(n(n-1)/2), unless the constraints themselves depend ont he number of nodes.

Comment: this is a standard problem; I think you're confused, since you are given the list of nodes, why ask then for the highest number of nodes? Nodes don't change... What's fast enough? Ya you can do this in polynomial time.

Comment: The second list of nodes, is it a map? every node in list1 can connect to any node in list2? or any specifics?

Comment: I forgot a constraint, I need all the nodes to be reachable from all the nodes.

I can't have A->B->C->A and D->E->F->D

Comment: I guess that 3. request should be updated to: "every node must connect to two other nodes" or something similar.

Comment: I edited to make clear the connections are one way.

Comment: @Dan: I don't understand the input. Is it two lists? or a kind of map? What's make a vertex A different then vertex B, if they are both in the first list? Or is it a Map, mapping each vertex to a list of possible nodes?

Comment: @amit: The input is a list of nodes (let say A, B, C and D) and a list of vertex they might have (A may be connected to B or D, B may be connected to A, C or D, C may be connected to D, etc.).

For each node I want to pick one vertex it will connect to while ensuring that I can follow a path from any point in the graph to any other point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you are trying to find an [Hamiltonian cycle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_path), which is a [NP-Complete problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_path_problem).

**Why is the problem equivalent to finding an Hamiltonian cycle:**

Let `n` be the number of nodes. Given the constraint that each node is connected to exactly one other node, the solution has `n` edges. Because each node has to be reachable, each node will be the tail of *at least* one edge. But the solution has `n` edges, so each node will be the tail of *exactly* one edge. The solution is thus a union of paths. The constraints that all edges have to be reachable from all other edges make the solution an Hamiltonian cycle.

Comment: This is correct: The given problem is equivalent to finding a Hamiltonian cycle. It would be nice if you could show why they are equivalent though.

Comment: This is not Hamiltonian cycle, maybe it could be Minimal Hamiltonian path aka. Traveling salesman which is NP-hard

Comment: @amit: The only way to solve the given constraints is to create a Hamiltonian cycle. Your solution of "a tree with all leaves later connected to the root" doesn't fit the contraints because the root would need to be connected to more than one node.

Comment: @interjay - I have edited my answer to show why the question reduces to finding an Hamiltonian cycle.

Comment: +1 Good answer, too bad the wrong answer was accepted though.

Comment: @interjay Yeah nice, while finding links one condition is edited, and one added and now you give downvotes :D

Answer (score 0):

Search for Directed Minimum Spanning Tree algorithm.

This looks OK:
http://www.utdallas.edu/~rbk/papers/dmdst.pdf

Also problem is NP-hard.

EDIT:
After edit it is Directed Hamiltonian cycle problem http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Directed_Hamilton_Cycle_Problem_is_NP-complete

Comment: Heh, given your constraint about number of max connections this is reduced to Traveling salesman problem.

Comment: A directed spanning tree doesn't fit the given constraint that any node is reachable from any other. For example, the root will not be reachable from any other node.

Comment: @interjay Yeah, but this condition was added later ;)

Comment: Well, it was added 7 minutes before your answer. It also does't seem right to talk about mimimum spanning tree and travelling salesman when the edges don't have weights.

Comment: @interjay Nope, both can be used without weights by using weight = 1. But now I see that there is no constraint that graph should be minimal, i tought there was, so we are back on basic Hamiltonian cycle. Lol